# vb.net Populate Combobox with comma separated values from an INI file

Tags: vb.net, combobox, ini

I'm attempting to add comma delimited values to a combobox.  The problem is I do not know if this is the best way to split the values into the combobox.  Is there a more cleaner/efficient way to do this?:

```
Dim toread As String
    toread = ini.ReadValue("Schools", "Schools")
    Dim textdelimiter As String
    textdelimiter = ","
    Dim splitout = Split(toread, textdelimiter)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To UBound(splitout)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(splitout(i))
    Next
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(ini.ReadValue("Schools", "Schools").Split(",").ToArray)
```

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for this, it's definitely an easier/cleaner way lol

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this, mostly because of the repeated word Schools.... Could one of you please explain what exactly is going on in this code?

Comment: @DougRobinson I don't know either.  :-)  It's actually not important since the OP didn't document that ini class, or what ReadValue did.  It looks like it's just a function that returns a comma-delimited string, so that's all that's happening here.